# Magento products grid filter with custom attribute

Tags: php, magento, filter, grid, admin

I've added a custom attribute to the products grid in the admin area using the following code in /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php under function _prepareColumns()

It works fine, but now when searching with any search filter - the new attribute column is showing no values.

```
$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product','custom_column');
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
$attributeData = $attribute->getData();
$frontEndLabel = $attributeData['frontend_label'];
$attributeOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

$attributeOptions2 = array();
foreach ($attributeOptions as $value) {
    if(!empty($value['value'])) {
        $attributeOptions2[$value['value']] = $value['label'];
    }
}

$this->addColumn('custom_column',
    array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Custom Column'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'custom_column',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'options' => $attributeOptions2,
));
```

And under _prepareCollection() I've added the following code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('custom_column');
```

I think it's simple but I'm not catching it at the moment, any help is highly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

When searching with filters - the column is populating with values EXCEPT if the filter was the Name column.

Comment: Didn't you try with manage attribute in catalog? there you can simply set "Use in Quick Search" field as yes!

Comment: Give this extension a try: https://github.com/tzyganu/GridEnhancer. It's free and it allows you to manage a lot of admin grids without writing any code.

Comment: @Marius, your extension looks very good, I've inspected the source code and tested it but unfortunately it didn't resolve the issue. In fact, my code above is showing values when filtering with any column except the Name column, but your extension is not showing any values for the new custom column at all.

Comment: Did you solved this issue? Please post the answer. I am in the same trouble

Answer (score 2):

I had to add the following to `_prepareCollection`:

```
        $collection->joinAttribute(
            'custom_column',
            'catalog_product/custom_column',
            'entity_id',
            null,
            'inner',
            $store->getId()
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add custom filter callback

```
$this->addColumn('custom_column',
  array(
    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Custom Column'),
    'width' => '150px',
    'index' => 'custom_column',
    'type'  => 'options',
    'options' => $attributeOptions2,
    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, 'filter_custom_column_callback'),
));
```

And define your filter query there, like in this example:

```
protected function filter_custom_column_callback($collection, $column)
{
    $filterValue = $column->getFilter()->getValue();
    $collection->getSelect()->where(" ... ");
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @maglater, but - can you please provide more detailed answer on what the query at $collection->getSelect()->where(" ... ") should look like?
I've tried many combinations but without any luck so far.

Comment: try $collection->addAttributeToFilter('custom_column', $filterValue); instead of $collection->getSelect()->where(" ... ");

Comment: tried $collection->addAttributeToFilter('custom_column', $filterValue);
Still the same.
The new column is not showing values ONLY when filtering with the "Name" column, other columns are working fine. Any idea why this particular column has issues with filtering the new added column?

Comment: after $collection->addAttributeToFilter('custom_column', $filterValue); add echo $collection->getSelect(); die; and check what SQL query it tries to execute during filtering.